# Cmd always start on wrong drive

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

For some reason when I do <kbd>Start</kbd>, <kbd>Run</kbd>, `cmd`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> it always starts at `M:`, one of several mapped network drives.

I'd rather have it start on `C:`, or in `C:\dev` if possible. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: It could be that drive M: is mapped as the user's "home" folder.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, that actually seems to be the case. So I suppose that's why it starts there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a shortcut to cmd.exe (on the desktop or in your Start menu) and right click on it, select properties.  I've forgotten what it's labeled in XP, but in Windows 7 it says "Start in:" put your directory in that box.

For a more permanent solution, you can edit the registry and change the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`'s `Autorun` value.  See [this](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/autoruncmd.htm) for details.

Comment: Used the shortcut trick. Worked perfectly, and doesn't mess with default behaviour and registry stuff :p

Comment: @Svish great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`, item `Autorun`.

If Autorun contains something like `CD /d M:\`, just change it to `CD /d C:\dev`.
If not, then let me know its value on your computer.